# Ymodem Buffer Start Address

Tags: memory, stm32

I am looking this source codes to use Ymodem protocole,

https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF4/blob/master/Projects/STM324xG_EVAL/Applications/IAP/IAP_Main/inc/ymodem.h

But I've a question about that,

Line 65 says to us as in below:

```
/* /-------- Packet in IAP memory ------------------------------------------\
 * | 0      |  1    |  2     |  3   |  4      | ... | n+4     | n+5  | n+6  | 
 * |------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 * | unused | start | number | !num | data[0] | ... | data[n] | crc0 | crc1 |
 * \------------------------------------------------------------------------/
 * the first byte is left unused for memory alignment reasons
```

According to this informaton PACKET_DATA_INDEX define 4. But I dont understand this because in the Ymodem includes data in 3th byte, why we choose the 4th byte or SOH is the 0th index of the frame, why we get this as a 1

[image]